# Storing files inside spyMemcached server?

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

I having an input (.JSON,.jpg,.txt,etc..).That file i need to store into memcached server.
    I don't want to convert file to Byte[] before passing to memcached server.
    If any possibility to store file inside Memcached server?
    I am using spymemcached tool.

Example:

```
MemcachedClient mc=new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress(192.168.7.104",11211));
File file=new File("D:\\test.txt");
mc.set("Key1",3600,file);
mc.get("Key1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to read from the file and stored the read data in memcached. A File object is only a handle to the file and doesn't actually contain the data stored in the file.